# Remotely turn off Sharing Wizard in Windows 7

Tags: windows, remote-access, sharing, registrykey

I am trying to figure out the registry key in Windows 7 that will turn off Sharing Wizard for a computer (not just a user).

Is this the key?

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\SharingWizardOn
```

But here is my problem, there are many values, and I don't know which one to change to Disable the Sharing Wizard on the Windows 7 computer

[image]

Which key do I change to 0?

Answer (score 1):

First, it isn't the key

```
HKEY_USERS\<userId>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\SharingWizardOn
```

but the `REG_DWORD` value called `SharingWizardOn` in the key:

```
HKEY_USERS\<userId>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

Second: replacing `<userId>` in the above path with `.DEFAULT` will only set it for new user accounts subsequently created (`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT` is used to initialise the new user's registry settings).

To set it for all users you need to change for each existing user profile.  This can be done by setting for each user (represented by their security ID – SID – rather than their user name). Iterating through all the subsekeys of `HKEY_USERS` that *do not end with `_Classes` would work.

Here the value looks like this in regedit (for my account, hence the path starting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` which is just an alias for `HKEY_USERS\<My Account SID>`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you are rigth!
Apply For all users

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\SharingWizardOn

Just change ..
CheckedValue to 0
And thats all
You do not need to restart!